# DataSets in C#.NET -- How to access related tables via a universal row

Tags: c#, database

I have a situation where previously a simple DataTable worked (because I was using an DataAdapter that only hit *one* table in my relation system).  Recently however I'm joining three tables (done in the query that gets sent to my rdb) and it looks can only access one via a DataTable.

Is there a way to iterate over some universal row (i.e. one row that has columns of all tables joined via a foreign key link) element in a DataSet?

Also currently all of this data from three tables is getting put into a single DataTable via OdbcDataAdapter.Fill(myDataTable).  I would really like to be able to do something like:

```
string s1 = myDataTable.Rows[i]["table1.someCol"],
       s2 = myDataTable.Rows[i]["table2.someCol"];
```

Are either of these possible, and if not how should one handle this situation?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: To say anything I think you should provide an example of your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was that among these several tables there were some columns with the same names.  I just distinguished them in the query by doing:

```
select table1.id as t1_id, table2 as t2_id ...
```

This way I don't have to do anything in the c# code because I can now access them directly from a single DataTable.